# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process Streamwriter

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, streamwriter

I am getting an error that my textfile that is used to create and save my dictionary is being used by another process, I have used Process explorer to no result on what could be using my file. Below is my code and the code throwing this error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace meade_9_10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private Dictionary<string, string> names = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            
        };

        public Form1()
        {
            //Make sure Form1 is loaded and ran on program open
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += Form1_Load;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Grab myfile.txt and convert to array
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("myfile.txt");
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] arr = line.Split(',');
                int i = 0;
                //Add array objects to names dictionary
                while (i < arr.Length)
                {
                    names[arr[i]] = arr[i + 1];
                    i += 2;
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            //declare variables
            string nameAdd;
            string emailAdd;
            //Put user input into variable
            nameAdd = txtNameAdd.Text;
            emailAdd = txtEmailAdd.Text;
            //Declare new dictionary key pair as user input
            names[emailAdd] = nameAdd;
            //clear the textbox controls
            txtNameAdd.Text = "";
            txtEmailAdd.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            string emailDel;
            emailDel = txtEmailDel.Text;
            //Remove key pair that is inputted by user
            names.Remove(emailDel);   
        }

        private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Declare variables
            string emailDel;
            string nameAdd;
            string emailAdd;
            //Assign values to variables
            emailDel = txtEmailChange.Text;
            nameAdd = txtNameNew.Text;
            emailAdd = txtEmailNew.Text;
            //Delete the user inputted email to change
            names.Remove(emailDel);
            //Add the new key pair values to dictionary
            names.Add(emailAdd, nameAdd);
        }

        private void btnLookUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            //Declare variable
            string email = txtEmail.Text;
            //If statement to check if dictionary contains key value
            if (names.ContainsKey(email))
            {
                outputName.Text = names[email];
                outputEmail.Text = email;
            }   
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //writes the names dictioanry to array inside text file
            File.WriteAllLines("myfile.txt",
            names.Select(x => x.Key + "," + x.Value ).ToArray());
            
            //Closes the program
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The part of my code giving me the error

System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\ALL SCHOOL FILES\Fall 2021\C#\meade_9_10\bin\Debug\myfile.txt' because it is being used by another process.'

is

```
            names.Select(x => x.Key + "," + x.Value ).ToArray());
```

I just cannot figure out what process is using my text file that is breaking this program, it was working earlier and I haven't made any changes except for removing redundant white space between functions.

Comment: When you read the file, you don't close the `StreamReader` afterwards.  The simplest fix is to use `File.ReadAllLines` to simplify the IO.

Comment: It's telling you the file is in use. Is it open in another program? There may even be an older version of your app running in the background.

Comment: I've changed the File.WriteAllLines to File.ReadAllLines and nothing has changed. I have scoured my processes and cannot find anywhere this file could be open besides the program when I run it.

Comment: it is because StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("myfile.txt"); you did this in Load, which never close. Should use using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("myfile.txt")){ ..... other code }

Answer (score 0):

Try using the
[StreamReader.Close()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.close) method after your innermost `while` loop:

> Closes the StreamReader object and the underlying stream, and releases any system resources associated with the reader.

Alternatively, you can use the [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement:

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.